# Latex Beamer \shade

Tags: beamer, presentations, integral

I have this code:

```
\begin{frame}
\pagestyle{empty}
  \frametitle{Tvorba grafu}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
      \shade[top color=blue,bottom color=gray] 
        (0,0) parabola (1.25,2.5) |- (0,0);
      \draw[line width=0.25, ->] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[above]  {$x$};
      \draw[line width=0.25, ->] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[right]  {$y$};
      \draw[style=help lines] (0.001,0.001) grid (3.9,3.9);
      \draw (0,0.25) parabola bend(0,0) (2,4) node[below right] {$x^2$};
      \foreach \x/\xtext in {1/1, 2/2, 3/3}
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\xtext$};
      \foreach \y/\ytext in {1/1, 2/2,3/3}
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\ytext$};
        \draw (1.1cm,2pt) node[above] {$\displaystyle\int_0^{3} \!\!x^2\mathrm{d}x$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Problem is in: 
`shade[top color=blue,bottom color=gray] (0,0) parabola (1.25,2.5) |- (0,0);` There is problem, Latex error.

But if i have this command:

```
\shade[top color=blue,bottom color=gray] (0,0) parabola (1.25,2.5) -| (0,0);
```

Its work, no error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is your question?

Comment: Welcome. Please provide a full compatible minimal working example(MWE): https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that . Started with `\documentclass` and ended with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Maybe this example will help you http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parabola-plot/. If not: What is your question?

Comment: Instead of `\pagestyle{empty}`, use `\begin{frame}[plain]`

Comment: Please STOP CLOSING this posting. The OP hasn't been back since posting, so s/he couldn't possibly clarify anything.

Answer (score 2):

Both shading commands works as expected. With

```
\shade[top color=blue,bottom color=gray]
      (0,0) parabola (1.5,2.25) |- (0,0);% shaded below of parabola
```

you obtain

[image]

and with

```
\shade[top color=blue,bottom color=gray]
      (0,0) parabola (1.5,2.25) -| (0,0);% shaded left of parabola
```

[image]

For my test I slightly rewrote your MWE (example from TikZ & PGF manual, pp. 874):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \frametitle{Tvorba grafu}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
% grid
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3.9,3.9);
% axis
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[above]  {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[right]  {$y$};
\foreach \i in {1, 2, 3}
{
    \draw (2pt,\i) -- + (-4pt,0) node[left]  {$\i$};
    \draw (\i,2pt) -- + (0,-4pt) node[below] {$\i$};
}
% parabola
\draw (0,0) parabola bend (0,0) (2,4) node[below right] {$x^2$};
\draw (1.05,0) node[above] {$\displaystyle\int_0^{3}\kern-1.75ex x^2\,\mathrm{d}x$};
\scoped[on background layer] 
\shade[top color=blue,bottom color=gray]
      (0,0) parabola (1.5,2.25) |- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Orthogonal coordinate `|-` mean first vertically then horizontally, and `-|` opposite. Is this your question?